# Call class method from another class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class-method

I realize this question is pretty basic, but I'm really stuck.  I have a plist. I'm trying to read that into an array so I can work with it in various classes. So in one class I have:

```
+ (NSArray*)questionArray
{
static NSArray* questions = nil;

if(!questions)
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Questions" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *questionsArray = [dic objectForKey:@"groups"];
    NSMutableArray *questionObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:     [questionsArray count]]; 

    for(NSDictionary* questionDic in questionsArray)
    {
        QuestionContainerObject* object = [[self alloc] initWithDictionary:questionDic];

        [questionObjects addObject:object];
        [object release];
    }

    questions = questionObjects;

    [dic release];
}

return questions;
}
```

I want to be able to access the things I pull out of the array from another class. I tried calling it like `NSString *str = [QuestionContainerObject questionArray];` from my other class (after importing the header) but I get the 'class method +questionArray not found' warning.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I'm really lost! Thanks!!

Comment: The warning suggest you have not declared the questionArray class method in the header file, or it is not declared in the @interface block for the class QuestionContainerObject. What happens when you run it does it work, or does it throw an exception.

Comment: whoops, you are so right. Fixed that, now everything is working.  Is this the proper way to call the method though? Do I always need to reference my QuestionContainerObject? Thanks, I've never worked with class methods before.

Comment: Yes that us correct, you can also from within a class method do [self otherClassMethod], classes are objects in Objective-C. If you are familiar with the factory object in design patterns, the class object is the factory object for instances of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is because the compiler does not know the questionArray method exists.
define this method in the header (QuestionContainerObject.h)

```
@interface QuestionContainerObject
+ (NSArray*)questionArray;
@end
```

and in the file using it:

```
#import QuestionContainerObject.h
```

Also remember to release objects created using [class alloc]

Comment: not if he's using arc .. it should be mandatory for iOS questions to include wether they use arc or not :D

Comment: SHE's not using ARC ;) Thanks for your help.

Is this the proper way to call the method though? Do I always need to reference my QuestionContainerObject? Thanks, I've never worked with class methods before.

Comment: Since classes are actually just objects as well, all class methods are messages sent to the class. So for instance: `[ClassName someClassMethod];` and you can call that from any class, and without instantiating an instance of the class first.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the class method declaration in the header file?

Btw, move the `static NSArray* questions = nil;` outside of the method body and remove the `= nil`, or else its not going to have the effect you wanted, i think.